# HTC Android Fails to mount- Mount from computer?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mount, android, sd-card

I Have an HTC Incredible S (S-Off, Rooted, ViperVIVO 1.3.0 ICS) that has seemingly ceased to posses the ability to mount its SD Storage to my computer. For whatever reason, whenever I plug in my device to transfer files from computer to phone and vice versa, the computer, for some reason, cannot actually access the phone.

I get prompted with a window on my phone when I first plug it in, asking me which mode I want to put the device into (Charge mode, tether mode, etc.), and even if I select the "Disk Drive" function, the phone still cannot successfully mount to my computer. The phone itself unmounts itself from the SD and says that the computer is connected, but again, it doesn't work.

Is there any way to force mount the device from my computer- either via command or otherwise? This should help in that if I unmount the SD from the phone I should be able to mount it to my computer, from my computer, Correct?